# optimized data base search algorithm

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, algorithm, real-time

I'm developing a website with api that can be accessed from mobile clients, the app is something similar to http://zomato.com/

lets say we have table car(carID, model, maker, transmission, fuleType, otherOptions)

the user can query any of the fields, the query also might include fields in other tables for example if i create w separate table for makers and models.

of course I can query using like clause on all fields, is that the right way ? when there might be thousands of records ?

I need fast db response real time querying when using either the mobile app or the website.

I'm familiar with .Net the most but i would be glad if you give me any other recommendations and guide me through the starting point(libraries, existing open source projects).

note: the user will only have a search field and optional filters like model, category etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i would do.

Build up your query using an `IQueryable`.  You can use if statements to check if any of your parameters have a value and if so append the where statement to your query.  Once your query is all set send it to memory with a `.ToList` or an `.AsEnumerable`.

```
public List<Data> Search (string param1, string param2)
{
    IQueryable<Data> query = db.SomeTable;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(param1))
        query = query.Where(m => m.Field1 == param1); // might use contain depending on your use case

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(param2))
        query = query.Where(m => m.Field2 == param2);

    return query.ToList();
}
```

I would also use a `Skip` and `Take` for pagination.

Edit: I wanted to note this is about as fast as you will get with a database that I know of, if anyone else knows a faster function please let me know.  You can achieve a quicker response by using a NoSQL database and static documents, but for several thousands of records a database should work just fine.

Comment: Yes i am aware of this technique for querying the database but in my case you won't know which field is he querying, so i was searching for something more advanced. and i wanted a way to give real time response to the API client for example when he types the first three characters result start filtering like search engines does, and i can not use documents it needs to be a database.

Comment: For an auto complete type of search box you would need a listing of keywords.  Would be best to create a table of all the keywords submitted and you can use a general rule that says if a keyword has been submitted X number of times add it to the keyword table that gets used for your auto complete.  You should also implement a white and black list for the keywords.  As for the query what you have should be just fine, multiple where statements on each field.  You most likely want to focus on database optimization which is outside of the query such as like indexes, caching, etc...

Comment: I like the idea of the black/white box,  then you mean i shall make two requests to the database(one initial to load auto complete data) the other is to get real results. I see what i'm trying to do is not much complicated as i thought, but since you mentioned NoSql, i have not used this before, i have read some articles about that but could not confirm if it can satisfy my needs (having relation ships between database entities), i don't want to change the subject of the question. but not sure if i shall go with relational database or shall i spend more time learning new techniques(the NoSql)

Comment: We are talking about well over millions of records with thousands of requests for NoSQL.  For your use case you should be just fine with a SQL database.